# Encoding System that Assign Same Number of Bits for Each Character

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, encoding-scheme

I am trying to get a binary string that has been converted from text of a text file, I am able to get that but the problem is, I need each character to be represented by same number of bits, but that is not what I get (**please see the below python code and corresponding output**).
For example, character `i` is represented by `1101001`, which is 7 bits long, but character  `!` is represented by `100001`, which is 6 bits long.

Is there any encoding/decoding system where each character takes same amount of bits?

```
content = open('a.txt', 'r').read()
test_str = content
# using join() + ord() + format()  ... Converting String to binary 

Binary = ' '.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)

#Decimal=int(Binary, 2)



# printing original string  
print("The original string is : " + str(test_str)) 
# printing result  
print("The string after Binary conversion : \n" + str(Binary))
```

**Output:**

```
The original string is : Hi! Is there a solution?
The string after Binary conversion : 
1001000 1101001 100001 100000 1001001 1110011 100000 1110100 1101000 1100101 1110010 1100101 100000 1100001 100000 1110011 1101111 1101100 1110101 1110100 1101001 1101111 1101110 111111
```

Comment: This is a python-specific programming question. The C counterpart supports obligatory leading zeroes (e.g. `%07b` in systems that support `%b`), and the python `format` likely also has such a mechanism. If not, it is easy to implement it yourself. You're a programmer! Be creative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to solve this problem is by adding leading zeroes. So `i` would still be represented by `1101001`, while `!` will be represented by `0100001`.

This is similar to how you digital clock might use 06:40 for 6:40, or 12:05 for 12:5.